# SMTP.Send(Mail) Error

Tags: vb.net, smtp

Here's my code (yes I censored my email/password) (when you click button)

```
Dim Mail As New MailMessage
Mail.Subject = "test email"
Mail.To.Add("*****")
Mail.From = New MailAddress("*****") '
Mail.Body = "This is an email!"
Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
SMTP.EnableSsl = True
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*****", "*****")
SMTP.Port = 587
SMTP.Send(Mail)
MsgBox("Sent Successfully")
```

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at (link which doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!
I never would have guessed.
Google wasn't letting me use my account because it was hacked. It apparently was hacked when I was writing code...

Answer (score 0):

FYI, a safer version would be

```
    Using mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage
        mail.Subject = "test email"
        mail.To.Add("*****")
        mail.From = New MailAddress("*****") '
        mail.Body = "This is an email!"
        Using smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            smtp.EnableSsl = True
            smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*****", "*****")
            smtp.Port = 587
            smtp.Send(mail)
        End Using
    End Using
    MsgBox("Sent Successfully")
```

This would ensure that the `mail` and `smtp` objects get cleaned up, whether or not an exception occurs.